# Проблема (permission)

Tags: android, android-studio

Программа требует при запуске разрешение от пользователя

> Отображать всплывающее окно, когда запущено в фоновом режиме

.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Установил из google play аналогичную программу ,заметил что разрешение

> Отображать всплывающее окно, когда запущено в фоновом режиме

уже стоит галочка ,хотя я разрешение не давал.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Программно его установить никак не получается.

**Как они это реализовали ???**

Comment: У Вас в AndroidManifest.xml есть строка `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />`?

Comment: нет ,а что все дело в нем ?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
В AndroidManifest.xml есть строка ,но разрешений нет

Comment: галочки также нету

Comment: А дайте ссылку на то приложение, которое без диалога разрешение получило, пожалуйста.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kairylab.android.simplealarm

Comment: Может у того приложения `targetApi` старше, чем было введено это разрешение - тогда оно получает его автоматически при установке

Comment: Это простой будильник я брал для примера ,я даже разобрал его код ничего особенного не могу найти .

Comment: У меня на телефоне вообще отдельной графой такого разрешения нет... постараюсь подумать, но вряд ли смогу помочь(

Comment: У этого будильника minSdkVersion="23" ,я сделал также ,но безрезультатно

Comment: @FloweR, ну если разобрали - посмотрите в его манифесте список `uses-permission` попробуйте себе добавить такие. По-моему интересующий вас пункт - это `android.permission.START_ACTIVITIES_FROM_BACKGROUND` либо `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`

Answer (score 0):

Все приложения из Google Play, которые заявляют это разрешение, получают его на устройстве без запросов. Запрос на устройстве нужен только для приложений не из Google Play.